# “There was a problem with the requested skills response”

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When using the "Alexa Emulator" during skill testing, my skill works very well (when typing my utterances).  However if I speak the same utterances to my Amazon Echo device, almost always it responds with, “There was a problem with the requested skills response”.  I have no way to debug the issue since there's no problems when running the Emulator.

I am speaking very clearly to my Amazon Echo device.  I've also tried changing my Skill invocation name, it doesn't avoid this issue.

Also, I didn't see any difference in the cloudwatch logs between the Echo Device and the Emulator.

Example utterances:

```
"Alexa, tell xxxxx xxxxx to start Michael Jackson Thriller"
"Alexa, tell xxxxx xxxxx to start watching Michael Jackson Thriller"
"Alexa, tell xxxxx xxxxx to start playing Michael Jackson Thriller"
```

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch logs for the lambda function will be recorded to the same log group as you would find them when you used the emulator. But this is not an uncommon situation, where the emulator will be ok and the actual device not work. Especially with media and other directives.